# Remove Tick Marks But Keep Axis Label ggplot2 R

Tags: r, ggplot2

Let's say I have the following data.frame:

```
    structure(list(x = c("item_1", "item_2", "item_3", "item_4"), 
        y = c("location_1", "location_2", "location_3", "location_4"
        )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

########################
#       x          y
#1 item_1 location_1
#2 item_2 location_2
#3 item_3 location_3
#4 item_4 location_4
```

With the following plot:

```
data %>% ggplot(aes(x,y)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

Is there a way **to keep all four labels** on the y-axis, but **only show tick marks for location_4 and location_1**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The theme element `axis.ticks.y` will take vectorized colours.

```r
data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x,y)) + 
  geom_point() +
  theme(axis.ticks.y = element_line(color = c("black", NA, NA, "black")),
        axis.ticks.length = unit(5, "points"))
```

[image]

Comment: Allan, you are the best! I didn't even think about altering the color. Thanks!